# how to reinitialize the subscription when I did transaction replication with backup

Tags: sql-server, backup, replication

I have some quetions about  tracsation replication in sqlserver 2008 r2,as you know,when your database is very large,you can use backup to initialize  tracsation replication,this will not need snapshotfiles,
what's my quetion is when my subcriber is wrong,how I can  reinitialize the subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would basically remove the subscription and start again, i.e. with another backup & restore, and then following the steps you used to initially setup the subscription.

Comment: it's so awful,there are any better ways to solve this problem.And,I think microsoft should have this solution,but I cannot find in its website."muhmud",are you did this before. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thing is @Tim, re-initialize is effectively the same as re-creating the subscription, i.e. you still have to send a full snapshot of data to the subscriber. The difference is, you don't need to re-create the subscription, which is a trivial task anyway. Remember, you don't need to recreate the publication, only the subscription.

Comment: hi muhmud,you mean I have to drop the subcriber and  then to create again use backup  or just retore with the newest backup in subcriber. Thank you.

Comment: That's right, just drop the subscriber, do a restore with latest backup, then setup the subscription again like you did the first time.

Comment: thank you,I haved verified.It's true.